# Why crystal report always tells Parameter is incorrect?when generate report dynamically in c#?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am developing a crystal report that is dynamically i added correct permeters
  even i checked with Paramfieldinfo property on crystalreportviewer it shows
  5 parameters with the name it is perfect.

But it still shows the "Parameter is incorrect" While creating parameters i have
  select the ListOfValues option is Dynamic.
  I struglled this porblem from 4 hrs i don't know where it is the can u tell me
  please thanks.

My code is :

```
        string query = "SELECT ";
        int columnNo = 0;

        if (chbCode.Checked)
        {
            columnNo++;
            query = query.Insert(query.Length, "Customer_Code as Column" +
            columnNo.ToString());

            paramField = new ParameterField();
            paramField.Name = "col" + columnNo.ToString();
            paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
            paramDiscreteValue.Value = "Customer Code";
            paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
            //Add the paramField to paramFields
            paramFields.Add(paramField);
        }
        if (chbFirstName.Checked)
        {
            columnNo++;
            if (query.Contains("Column"))
            {
                query = query.Insert(query.Length, ", ");
            }
            query = query.Insert(query.Length, "FirstName as Column" +
            columnNo.ToString());

            paramField = new ParameterField();
            paramField.Name = "col" + columnNo.ToString();
            paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
            paramDiscreteValue.Value = "First Name";
            paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
            //Add the paramField to paramFields
            paramFields.Add(paramField);
        }
        if (chbLastName.Checked)
        {
            columnNo++; //To determine Column number
            if (query.Contains("Column"))
            {
                query = query.Insert(query.Length, ", ");
            }
            query = query.Insert(query.Length, "LastName as Column" +
            columnNo.ToString());

            paramField = new ParameterField();
            paramField.Name = "col" + columnNo.ToString();
            paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
            paramDiscreteValue.Value = "Last Name";
            paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
            //Add the paramField to paramFields
            paramFields.Add(paramField);
        }
        if (chbAddress.Checked)
        {
            columnNo++;
            if (query.Contains("Column"))
            {
                query = query.Insert(query.Length, ", ");
            }
            query = query.Insert(query.Length, "Address as Column" +
            columnNo.ToString());

            paramField = new ParameterField();
            paramField.Name = "col" + columnNo.ToString();
            paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
            paramDiscreteValue.Value = "Address";
            paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
            //Add the paramField to paramFields
            paramFields.Add(paramField);
        }
        if (chbPhone.Checked)
        {
            columnNo++;
            if (query.Contains("Column"))
            {
                query = query.Insert(query.Length, ", ");
            }
            query = query.Insert(query.Length, "Phone as Column" +
            columnNo.ToString());

            paramField = new ParameterField();
            paramField.Name = "col" + columnNo.ToString();
            paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
            paramDiscreteValue.Value = "Phone";
            paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
            //Add the paramField to paramFields
            paramFields.Add(paramField);
        }

        //if there is any remaining parameter, assign empty value for that 
        //parameter.
        for (int i = columnNo; i < 5; i++)
        {
            columnNo++;
            paramField = new ParameterField();
            paramField.Name = "col" + columnNo.ToString();
            paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
            paramDiscreteValue.Value = "";
            paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
            //Add the paramField to paramFields
            paramFields.Add(paramField);
        }

        crystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;

        query += " FROM Customer";
        return query;
```

Please solve my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it like this:

```
CrystalReportSource1.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue(0, "ParameterValue");
```

Comment: CrystalReportSource1 does not exist in the current context error message is shown jack. And also what is "parameterValue" What will i pass in this parametervalue, becz i will retrieve the data from database that is stored in dataset so now i want to assign these values to crystal report based up on user selection. So in my case what is my parameter value. I provided checkboxes for user selection. Thanks.

Comment: I solved crystaldecision.web dll after added. But it shows crystalReportSource1 is never assigned and will always its default value is null. NullReference Exception is raised which value i will provide here. I am new to crystal report can u tell me jack?

Comment: I solved above issue too but it raises an "The report file was an empty"  what it tells? i created report document object and assign path of crystal report also it tells like that Thanks.

Comment: Can u tell me what is myparameter and parameterValue in setParameterValue method and why it is shown 'The report file was an empty' it loaded perfectly.Thanks

Comment: Are you passing parameters to your main report or do you have a sub report inside your main report when you are passing them dynamically like this? @Nag

Comment: No jack actually i have created parameters from the FieldExplorer window On parameter fields--> then click on new--> like this i created parameters in that i set parameter name is col1 and list of values option is dynamic. In the new parameter dialogue box. I doesn't have any sub report. After created parameters then just drag and drop on my report. It is displayed filed on report like this (?col1).

Comment: Now how can i pass values for this parameter name i know in my case (?col1) but what is the value for this?I got the data based on sql query got from the user. and i got the data in dataset but it is not displayed in my report. What is this issue? Thanks

Comment: one more issue i have jack when i click on my report button it dispalys prompt message for enter parameter values. why it is asking? i searched a lot in google but i didn't get any help. Can you tell me?@jack Thanks.